# How to only run Firebase GitHub action if a commit was verified?

Tags: firebase, github, github-actions

I have this default Firebase deploy-on-push workflow that does a great job updating my site whenever I push my code to my GitHub repository. However, I'd like to update the workflow such that my site is only updated if the commit was verified, as I don't want any unverified committers having the ability to update the site. (Of course, if a verified committer commits after an unverified committer, the whole site should update with the latest changes.)

The workflow is below.

```yaml
# This file was auto-generated by the Firebase CLI
# https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

name: Deploy to Firebase Hosting on merge
'on':
  push:
    branches:
      - master
jobs:
  build_and_deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
        with:
          repoToken: '${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}'
          firebaseServiceAccount: '${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_WOOSTER_TRADING_SYSTEMS }}'
          channelId: live
          projectId: wooster-trading-systems
```

Is this even possible? Can you do actions conditionally, and can you distinguish between unverified and verified committers inside the YAML setup?